# route paramMap do not trigger when parameter are removed

Tags: angular

I have the following route setup

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: 'dancers',
      component: DancersComponent,
      children: [
        {
          path: './list',
          component: DancersListComponent,
        },
        {
          path: './add/:id',
          component: DancersAddComponent,
        },
        {
          path: '/:id',
          component: DancersComponent,
        },
      ],
    },
  ]
```

in My `DancersComponent` I am listening to the route parameters

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.firstChild.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
      this.advertiserId = params.get('id')
    })
  }
```

this works fine when I move to a route with a parameter, the observable trigger.
But if I move from a route with a parameter to a route without, it doesn't trigger.

I would like it to trigger at all times. how can I achieve this ?

ex :

dancers/list => dancers/3 => the obs trigger with id = 3
dancers/3 => dancers => the obs never trigger (I would like it to provide id=undefined)

EDIT :

I tried

dancerComponent.ts

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.firstChild?.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
      console.log(params)
      this.advertiserId = params.get('id')
      this.changeDetector.detectChanges()
    })
  }
```

and routing :

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: 'dancers',
      component: DancersComponent,
      children: [
       {
          path: '',
          pathMatch: 'full',
          redirectTo: 'dancers/list',
        },
        {
          path: './list',
          component: DancersListComponent,
        },
        {
          path: './add/:id',
          component: DancersAddComponent,
        },
        {
          path: '/:id',
          component: DancersComponent,
        },
      ],
    },
  ]
```

but it still doesn't trigger when id disappear.

Comment: Could you create a StackBlitz? Also, I'm not sure `dancers` alone is a valid route. If it was `dancers/3 => dancers/list`, then I think you should see `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an empty path for that

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: 'dancers',
      component: DancersComponent,
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          component: create new component for that or show list component,
        },
        {
          path: './list',
          component: DancersListComponent,
        },
        {
          path: './add/:id',
          component: DancersAddComponent,
        },
        {
          path: '/:id',
          component: DancersComponent,
        },
      ],
    },
  ]
```

Comment: to visit the route dancers you should have an empty path, that is the way you can do it while paramMap only works if the route is like dancers/:id or dancers/add/:id

Comment: I tried this way, it doesn't work, and actually now it triggers only once.

Comment: you can see how I do it in image in that link https://pasteboard.co/Jfq4AQC.png

Comment: Image not found

Comment: see this link https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/daily-news-stream.appspot.com/o/user%2FdUoPfdwazddEYiNJYG7gNIsMZHu2%2F-MB2COO8lOkzeYip7QeF.PNG?alt=media&token=c94e3a40-8b99-4392-88f0-4dee87602816